# Как получить аргументы deeplink в Aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Всем привет

В aiogram 2 deeplink получить можно было с помощью

```
message.get_args()
```

Но в данной версии это не работает
Как получить его в v3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение

```
@admin_router.message(Command('info'))
async def get_user_info(message: types.Message,
                        command: CommandObject):
    args = command.args
    await message.answer(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не нашёл конкретную замену, но точно можно так

```
start_command, *args = msg.text.split()
```

Comment: Думал так сделать, но к счастью нашел решение. Все равно спасибо!